# Place patterns on polyline in iOS using Xamarin.forms.maps

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maps

Im using xamarin.forms.maps and successfully getting the polyline but I want to get some patterns on it as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMfV.png) and not able to achieve it.

Can anyone please help me in solving this issue and my code is as below :

formsMap.DrawPolyLine = () =>

{

if (nativeMaps == null)

{

nativeMaps = Control as MKMapView;

}

nativeMaps.OverlayRenderer = GetOverlayRenderer;

```
                CLLocationCoordinate2D[] coords = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[IOSMapViewModel.DeviceTrackData.Count];
                int index = 0;
                foreach (var position in IOSMapViewModel.DeviceTrackData)
                {
                    coords[index] = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(position.Latitude, position.Longitude);
                    index++;
                }

                routeOverlay = MKGeodesicPolyline.FromCoordinates(coords);
                if (nativeMap.Overlays != null)
                    nativeMaps.RemoveOverlays(nativeMap.Overlays);
                IMKOverlay overlay = routeOverlay;

                nativeMaps.AddOverlay(routeOverlay, MKOverlayLevel.AboveLabels);
            };
            nativeMap.GetViewForAnnotation = GetViewForAnnotation;
            nativeMap.CalloutAccessoryControlTapped += OnCalloutAccessoryControlTapped;
        }
    }


    MKOverlayRenderer GetOverlayRenderer(MKMapView mapView, IMKOverlay overlayWrapper)
    {
        if (polylineRenderer == null && !Equals(overlayWrapper, null))
        {
            var overlay = Runtime.GetNSObject(overlayWrapper.Handle) as IMKOverlay;
            Foundation.NSNumber[] dashValues = { 3, 6 };
            polylineRenderer = new MKPolylineRenderer(overlay as MKGeodesicPolyline)
            {
                FillColor = UIColor.Orange,
                StrokeColor = UIColor.Orange,
                LineWidth = 3,
                Alpha = 1f,
                LineDashPattern = dashValues
            };
            //polylineRenderer.CreatePath();
        }
        return polylineRenderer;
    }
```

Comment: Whts wrong? What errors are you gets?

Comment: Please click on the above link so that you get an image. I want polyline to look alike poyline in that image.